# How to input automatically when running a shell over SSH?

Tags: shell, ssh

In my shell script I am running a command which is asking me for input.

How can I give the command the input it needs automatically?

For example:

```
$cat test.sh
ssh-copy-id tester@10.1.2.3
```

When running test.sh:

- First, it will ask:

  `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`
- Then, it will ask me to input the password:

  `tester@10.1.2.3's password:`

Is there a way to input this automatically?

Comment: This is explained here: [Simplest way to automatically insert password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77126887/18179479)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For general command-line automation, [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) is the classic tool. Or try [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) if you're more comfortable with Python.

Here's a similar question that suggests using Expect: [Use expect in bash script to provide password to SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command)

Comment: We should really stop promoting expect as a way to automate ssh. Ssh purposely makes these prompts difficult to automate to push us to use the right solutions: command-line flags to bypass confirmations and public/private keys to eliminate password prompts.

Comment: That's ideal, but the real world is often not ideal. For the question as posed, that's the typical way to do it. If you used keys, you'd probably want a password on your key too, and then you may well be in the same situation. Sure, you could `ssh-agent`, `keychain`, etc. but sometimes there are reasons that's inconvenient or impractical.

Answer (score 48):

For simple input, like two prompts and two corresponding fixed responses, you could also use a "here document", the syntax of which looks like this:

```
test.sh <<!
y
pasword
!
```

The << prefixes a pattern, in this case '!'. Everything up to a line beginning with that pattern is interpreted as standard input. This approach is similar to the suggestion to pipe a multi-line echo into ssh, except that it saves the fork/exec of the echo command and I find it a bit more readable. The other advantage is that it uses built-in shell functionality so it doesn't depend on expect.

Comment: I take it back, ssh prompts via a tty device, which bypasses stdin. In the words of Emily Litella, "never mind". :)

Comment: Alas! after wasting a couple of hours... found the best solution, thanks.

Comment: The title doesn't specify SSH, so while this isn't applicable to the OP, other people finding the question can need, and use, this answer. BTW, herestring syntax -- `<<<$'y\npasword'` -- is potentially useful to others as well.

Answer (score 8):

There definitely is... Use the spawn, expect, and send commands:

```
spawn test.sh
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
send "yes"
```

There are more examples all over Stack Overflow, see:
[Help with Expect within a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575702/help-with-expect-within-a-bash-script)

You may need to install these commands first, depending on your system.

Comment: We should really stop promoting expect as a way to automate ssh. Ssh purposely makes these prompts difficult to automate to push us to use the right solutions: command-line flags to bypass confirmations and public/private keys to eliminate password prompts.

Comment: What if it's a 3rd-party script, and command line flags aren't available?

Comment: @HarshVerma The answer has no warnings or caveats so I stand by my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can pipe the answers to the script:

```sh
printf "y\npassword\n" | sh test.sh
```

where `\n` is escape-sequence

Answer (score 2):

**ssh-key with passphrase, with keychain**

keychain is a small utility which manages ssh-agent on your behalf and allows the ssh-agent to remain running when the login session ends. On subsequent logins, keychain will connect to the existing ssh-agent instance. In practice, this means that the passphrase must be be entered only during the first login after a reboot. On subsequent logins, the unencrypted key from the existing ssh-agent instance is used. This can also be useful for allowing passwordless RSA/DSA authentication in cron jobs without passwordless ssh-keys.

To enable keychain, install it and add something like the following to ~/.bash_profile:

eval `keychain --agents ssh --eval id_rsa`
From a security point of view, ssh-ident and keychain are worse than ssh-agent instances limited to the lifetime of a particular session, but they offer a high level of convenience. To improve the security of keychain, some people add the --clear option to their ~/.bash_profile keychain invocation. By doing this passphrases must be re-entered on login as above, but cron jobs will still have access to the unencrypted keys after the user logs out. The keychain wiki page has more information and examples.

Got this info from;

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90853/how-can-i-run-ssh-add-automatically-without-password-prompt

Hope this helps

I have personally been able to automatically enter my passphrase upon terminal launch by doing this: (you can, of course, modify the script and fit it to your needs)

1. edit the bashrc file to add this script;

   ## Check if the SSH agent is awake

   if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
   exec ssh-agent bash -c "ssh-add ; $0"
   echo "The SSH agent was awakened"
   exit
   fi

   ## Above line will start the expect script upon terminal launch.

   ./ssh.exp

here's the content of this expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

set passphrase "test"

spawn "./keyadding.sh"

expect "Enter passphrase for /the/path/of/yourkey_id_rsa:"

send "$passphrase\r";

interact
```

Here's the content of my keyadding.sh script (you must put both scripts in your home folder, usually /home/user)

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh-add /the/path/of/yourkey_id_rsa

exit 0
```

**I would HIGHLY suggest encrypting the password on the .exp script as well as renaming this .exp file to something like term_boot.exp or whatever else for security purposes.** Don't forget to create the files directly from the terminal using nano or vim (ex: `nano ~/.bashrc | nano term_boot.exp`) and also a `chmod +x script.sh` to make it executable. A `chmod +r term_boot.exp` would be also useful but you'll have to add sudo before ./ssh.exp in your bashrc file. So you'll have to enter your sudo password each time you launch your terminal. For me, it's more convenient than the passphrase cause I remember my admin (sudo) password by the hearth.

Also, here's another way to do it I think; 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/

Will certainly change my method for this one when I'll have the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the expect script as follow:

```
$ vi login.exp

#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh username@machine.IP
expect "*assword: "
send -- "PASSWORD\r"
interact
```

And run it as:

```
$ expect login.exp
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is for sudo password - simplest of all:

transform `<your-command>` into this:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S ls | <your-command>
```