# Controlling a bash shell using the process class with .NET Core 2.0

Tags: bash, .net-core

Using .NET Core 2.0 on a Linux Ubuntu I want to start a bash shell
using the Process class, redirect StandardInput and StandardOutput 
and want to enter commands and receive the results.

This works great for commands like `cd` and `dir`.

When I want to execute a command with `sudo`, the bash hangs, however,
and waits for the input of a password. I guess the same would happen
for commands that require a confirmation by Yes or No.

Is there any way to enter the password or a confirmation like Yes or No
from my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is, drop the 'netcore' tag from your search and look at pure bash-based answers like [Is there a way to input automatically when running a shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075478/is-there-a-way-to-input-automatically-when-running-a-shell)

Option 2, is there, or can you create, a username/password you can use that doesn't require sudo? If so then [the right `Process.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-2.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_System_Security_SecureString_System_String_) overload might do the trick? I hoped that there might be something on `ProcessInfo` class to request elevated privileges. On Windows platforms, using `Verb="runas"` does it but will invoke UAC.

Options 3: Forget sudo and look at other Linux options such as creating an executable with `setuid` set on it. Look at e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/262809/correct-way-to-give-elevated-privileges-to-mono-application for some thoughts.

Comment: Very helpful options. Following option 1 I found the interesting (but controversial) command "echo TopSecretPassword | sudo -S whatever". I'm not yet sure what will work best. Needs more testing...