# How to enter password to unlock key in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, openssl, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am writing a bash file to automate a process. For this I created a new password-encrypted key using:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 | openssl ec -out key-file.pem -aes128 -passout: pass:foobar
```

It works perfectly with the password being `foobar`.
Eventually I am using the following command in my scirpt:

```
seth account create --nonce=0 --wait keyAliasName
```

and on CMD it says:

> Enter passphrase to unlock keyAliasName.

I tried:

```
echo foobar | seth account create --nonce=0 --wait keyAliasName
```

but that says:

> ERROR: ERROR Reading the passphrase.

How to solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: maybe is the line break, try `echo -n foobar`

Comment: Do you call `seth account import key-file.pem keyAliasName` before `seth account create --nonce=0 --wait keyAliasName`?

Comment: @ReneKnop yes I do.

Comment: @nbari I had tried that. Gave same error

Comment: What's  the *seth*?

Comment: @EmilyE. heard of blockchain? I am oversimplifying this when I say: seth is a mix of two blockchains - hyperledger sawtooth and ethereum.Look here: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/seth/releases/latest/seth_developers_guide/getting_started.html. SETH uses ethereum's VM (or EVM) into sawtooth.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is more related to a topic like: *How to input automatically in bash*, like discussed e.g. in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075478/is-there-a-way-to-input-automatically-when-running-a-shell).

You are trying to input the password `foobar` to `seth` with the following line (right?):

```
echo foobar | seth account create --nonce=0 --wait keyAliasName
```

But `seth` prompts "*Enter passphrase to unlock keyAliasName*" and then wants to *read* the passphrase as user input.

So what you can do, is to use an `expect` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./your_script.sh
expect "Enter passphrase to unlock keyAliasNam"
send "foobar\n"
interact
```

Answer (score 0):

The `expect` approach might work, if you have it available in your environment. This answer expands on the cause of your issue. That seems to be the way the [ReadPassword()](https://gowalker.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal#ReadPassword) function in Go's `x/crypto/ssh/terminal` is implemented.

Others have run into it as well: it is reported as an issue with Go that was still active a few weeks ago: [x/crypto/ssh/terminal: ReadPassword doesn't work on redirected stdin giving inappropriate ioctl for device #19909](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19909). It includes a simple reproducer, in the section "What did you do?".

For a native `bash` approach, there does not seem to be any workaround for it at the moment, other than modifying the `sawtooth-seth` code in the [getPassword()](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-seth/blob/64ae353abf090d8daacb9d2c5d28655c48180e8a/cli/src/seth_cli/cli/data.go#L181) function to follow the approach mentioned [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19909#issuecomment-400857814).

P.S.: it would have been easier to figure out the problem if you had provided the *exact* error output: `Error reading password` as opposed to `ERROR Reading the passphrase.`