# Type a text on shell prompt

Tags: bash, shell, readline

Is there any way in the shell script by which I can set the input line programmatically? Consider the following scenario.

Let's say I make a script to create a git branch, and right after it is done making a branch, I don't want to switch to new branch programmatically, but just give user the command displayed on the prompt, so user don't have to type the command to switch to new branch but only just press enter key if he wants to run the displayed command.

```
read -p "Enter your branch name: " N
git branch $N
render-text-on-prompt "git checkout $N"
```

Execution:

```
$ ./mkbranch
$ Enter your branch name: change-93
$ git checkout change-93 _
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82630/put-text-in-the-bash-command-line-buffer and https://superuser.com/questions/1462995/how-to-create-a-bash-function-that-return-to-the-current-prompt

Comment: I usually do this sort of thing with `tmux paste-buffer`.  The script loads the command into the buffer and then pastes it.  The user can then either hit return, or cancel (or edit) the command interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't have a way to "preload" the next input buffer (unlike `zsh`, in which you can simply use `print -z "git checkout $N"`). You would need to have `mkbranch` handle the input (and subsequently execute the entered command) itself.

```
read -p "Enter your branch name: " N
git branch "$N"
read -e -i "git checkout $N" cmd
eval "$cmd"
```

`-e` informs `read` to use the Readline library for entering the line of text; the `-i` option preloads the input buffer.  (Without the `-e` the `-i` doesn't do anything.)

Note that `read -e` does not itself know anything about `bash` syntax, so there are no implicit line continuations; this makes it distinctly different from the ordinary `bash` prompt.

An alternative would be to simply *ask* the user if they would like to checkout the newly created branch:

```
read -p "Enter your branch name: " N
git branch "$N"
read -e -i Y -p "Checkout branch $N? (Y/n)"
[[ $REPLY == Y ]] && git checkout "$N"
```

Hitting enter accepts the pre-loaded Y to trigger the hard-coded `checkout command; any other command skips it. Either way, the script ends and returns to the regular command prompt.

Comment: You could set `READLINE_LINE`, but the documentation says it only works in `bind -x`.

Comment: I'm not sure assigning to it is useful even there; I think it's just a way for the code bound to a key by `bind -x` to access the current command-line buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a switch to check what the user input is.

```
function render_text_on_prompt {
    if [[ -z ${1} ]]; then # The argument passed into the function is empty/not set
        echo "Wrong usage!"
        return 1
    fi

    # Print the argument
    echo "${1} - Hit the enter key to run this command or anything else to abort"

    read INPUT_STRING
    case ${INPUT_STRING} in # Check what the user entered
        "") # User entered <enter>
            ${1}
            break
            ;;
        *) # User entered anything but enter
            echo "Nothing changed"
            break
            ;;
    esac
    return 0
}
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stub, which can be adapted as needed:

```
c="echo foo bar" ; read -p "Run '$c' [Y/n]? " n ; \
[ ! "$n" ] || [ "$n" = Y ] || [ "$n" = y ] && $c
```

The last line will run command `$c` if the user types *Enter*, `y` or `Y`.  Example run:

```
Run 'echo foo bar' [Y/n]?
```

User hits *Enter*:

```
foo bar
```

Comment: D'oh, this is a *POSIX* shell version... a `bash` version would be more succinct.  Pending...

Comment: The `bash` tag was added by Jonathan Leffler, not OP.

Comment: @melpomene: The use of `-p` on the `read` command made it 'not POSIX' — POSIX `read` (command) only supports the `-r` option.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Odd, the code above runs in `dash` and `bash --posix`.  Aha, but not `posh`!  Evidently some *POSIX* shells are more *POSIX* than others...

Answer (score 0):

**expect** is your friend.

This allows you to automate interactions with programs that require user input by scripting the expected responses.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn /path/to/interactive_program

expect "Username:"
send "your_username\r"

expect "Password:"
send "your_password\r"

# Continue with additional interactions as needed

# Wait for the program to finish
expect eof
```

In this example, the script uses the "spawn" command to start an interactive program, then uses "expect" to wait for specific patterns (like "Username:" or "Password:") in the program's output. The "send" command is used to provide responses.

Please note that using "expect" for automation can be powerful but may have security implications, especially when handling sensitive information like passwords. Care should be taken to handle such information securely.

Related question here:

[Expect within a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575702/expect-within-a-bash-script)